# Tour view does not have React internal Fiber

Tags: react-native

I want implementation app-tour in my project , I installed react-native-app-tour  .I have a View that I want assign app-tour to it and I use ref in view that it dispatch AppTourView to inputreducer and finally in useEffect I run appTour but when I run app I encountered Error that error is Tour view does not have React internal Fiber, please can help me

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useReducer,
  useRef,
} from 'react';
import {AppTour, AppTourSequence, AppTourView} from 'react-native-app-tour';

const inputReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type == 'SET_APPTOUR') {
    return [...state.appTour, action.data];
  }
};
export default function HomeScreen(props) {
const [forsat, setForSat] = useState(null);
  const [appTourTargets, dispatchAppTour] = useReducer(inputReducer, {
    appTour: [],
  });
 useEffect(() => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(appTourTargets);
      let appTourSequence = new AppTourSequence();
      appTourTargets.appTour.forEach(appTourTarget => {
        appTourSequence.add(appTourTarget);
      });
      AppTour.ShowSequence(appTourSequence);
    }, 1000);
  }, [appTourTargets]);

return(
<view style={styles.container}>
             <View
        ref={useCallback(ref => {
          if (!ref) return;

          setForSat(ref);
          let prop = {
            order: 12,
            title: 'This is a target View',
            description: 'We have the best targets, believe me',
            outerCircleColor: '#3f52ae',
            cancelable: false,
          };
          dispatchAppTour({type:'SET_APPTOUR', data:AppTourView.for(ref, {...prop})});
        }, [])}
        style={styles.rankContainer}>
        <BText font="_Light" size={15} color={color.firstColor}>
          فرصت{' '}
          <BText font="_Bold" color={color.secondColor} size={15}>
            {FormatHelper.toPersianString(daysToGo.toString())}
          </BText>{' '}
          روز تا کنکور
        </BText>
      </View>

     </view>
   )
}
```

Comment: same issue with RN 0.62